# Why is a form's submit event not firing (jQuery)?

Tags: form-submit, jquery

I have a form + layout like so:

```
<form ...>
    <div id="editor">
        [form html]
        <input type="submit" value="Submit form" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And the following javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var form = $('#editor').parents('form');
    alert(form.length); // this alerts "1"
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function() {
        alert('document form submit fired'); // this works as expected (alerts)
    });
    form.on('submit', function() {
        alert('selected form submit fired'); // this is never alerted
    });
});
```

This form is not loaded via ajax. When the page loads, the first dialog alerts "1". However when submitting the form, only one alert is fired -- the one that triggers submit for all forms in the document.

Why would this happen?

Comment: Works for me in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sERhZ/ Maybe something is wrong with your html or even setup?

Comment: In fact, given the handlers, the one applied directly to the form should (and does) fire first. Is this your complete code? Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I bet you have `return false` on the first handler preventing from the second to fire. Am I right?

Comment: @gdoron - the handler on the form should fire first as it is applied lower in the DOM than the document-level handler.  Something else is missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[It does work](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/CuGmr/). Something else is happening which is preventing the second alert from firing.

Comment: You are right. There was other code interfering. I was wondering what it could be. Turns out I had a bug when overriding $.validator.settings.highlight and $.validator.settings.unhighlight.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Your form selector is incorrect.</s>

Try and do this

```
$("form").on('submit', function() {
```

Pretty sure this should work

Actually if nothing is being loaded through ajax or dynamically through javascript

You can just do

```
$("form").submit(function() {
```

**EDIT**

Scratch my above.  Didn't see you set the value of form.  Check out http://jsfiddle.net/s3fvM/1/.  Seems to be working fine to me.  both are firing and alerting.

Comment: `form` is a variable holding the jQuery-wrapped form element.

Comment: Yea i see that now.  I just did this in jsfiddle and both are being fired.  [http://jsfiddle.net/s3fvM/](http://jsfiddle.net/s3fvM/1/)